# Creating Event for Multiple Forms

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I have tried a bunch of different things, so obviously I am now stuck...  I have created a form, it has a button on it - that when clicked creates a new form.  I can click away and create multiple forms this way.  What I would like and can not get to work is to have the main form have a second button on it - that when clicked will change all of the background colors on the secondary forms.

Thanks - I am guessing I close, but then again - close doesn't work...

Comment: Keep references on opened forms in collection, iterate over that collection in the event handler where you want to change background color and change background color for each form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bascally you do not need event or delegate type of things to solve this issue. In your secondary forms write a public method to change background color. Keep a list of secondary forms and when button is clicked just loop through all your secondary forms and call the color changing methods

**Using events**

In your parent form do something like this.

```
private event Action<Color> ChangeColor;

private void CreateAndShowForm()
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    ChangeColor += form2.changeColor;
    /*do other stuff to show form*/
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColor(Color.Red);
}
```

In the child forms

```
public void changeColor(Color obj)
{
    /*change background color*/
}
```

Comment: thanks - I know I could do that...  I was just hoping to do it through events rather than methods on the main form.  kinda like the main yells out "change colors!"  and each of the sub forms can decide what to do about that.  :-)

the end program is going to be a bit more complicated than just a color change - like something like "Photon Torpedo Attack" which could do any number of things based on the current state of the sub form.

Comment: Actually here the main is yelling out. It is not changing colors. It is the secondary forms who are changing colors (deciding what to do). But yes, you could also use events and in my opinion it is just a different syntax doing the same thing.

Comment: Muctadir, Yep - thats exactly what i would like to know how to do.  :-)

Comment: thanks!  very simple i see now, but i was about 50 lines of code going around and around in circles as i do when i cant figure things out...  :-)  thanks again, very easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this, but one way is to keep a collection of all child Forms in the main form and call a custom `change background color` method on each of them. You can create a ChildFormBase class that they all can inherit from where you can define the method to avoid repeating it in all child forms.

You can also do this with an event that you raise in the MainForm that the child forms can subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, when an event is raised, all the objects listening to it (registered as event listeners) are notified that the event has been raised and execute the respective event handler. Therefore, in your case, each **subform** should be registered to the specific event of the **main form**, as an event listener. Each time the **main form** raises the event, the **subforms** will be notified that the event has been raised and act accordingly.

You could see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a guide to the events paradigm in C#.

Hope I helped!